# How to find a series of unique integers from an array using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I have an array

arr = [2,1,3,1,4,1,3]

I have to find and remove the sequence such that only unique elements remain in an array.

**output**

suppose we found [1,1,3] subsequence and after deletion of 1,1,3 
the array will look like this [2,4,1,3]

now this array has become unique.

I am thinking of some solution using dynamic programming but I am not able to think of some good solution. Can anyone help me with some hint?

Comment: So you just have to remove the elements that have repeated?

Comment: Are you trying to find the sequence of the first appearance of each integer using dynamic programming?

Comment: @SadmanSakib yes

Comment: Another possibility if the range of numbers isn't too big relative to the size of the array: bucket-sort. E.g., if you have 1000 numbers ranging from 0-99, use an array of 100 bits, parse your input array, and set the relevant bit to '1'.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need dynamic programming.

In the simplest case for every element find the first occurence in array and delete item if index differs. Quadratic algorithm.

If you have memory, make hash map, put elements if they are new and delete otherwise (linear approach if we don't consider removing)